# Web Python Question

Tags: python, hosting, shared-hosting

Can anyone assist me in getting a Python script running on Hostgator Shared hosting? I work with PHP mostly, but have taken a liking to Python, and would like to try to get it going on the web. The only way I've ever ran Python is with either the interpreter, or through a terminal, with >Python file.py. I tried just uploading a hello world file to the webserver, but all it outputs is the script source. I talked with hostgator, but all they could tell me was I need to use a dispatcher, which I cannot seem to find an example of. All I want to know, is how to make a <p>Hello</p> output to the browser.

Thanks, and sorry if I'm rambley, I've been Googling this off and on all week now.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I got [this](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/getting-started/general-help/perl-and-python-http://docs.python.org/library/cgiscripts) from Hostgator's own support site.

Assuming your host is running Python 2.x, then you can adapt the linked-to script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html><head>"
print "<title>CGI Test</title>"
print "</head><body>"
print "<p>Test page using Python</p>"
print "</body></html>"
```

and put it in your `cgi-bin` folder with permissions of 755.

**Update:** In terms of "getting around" the cgi-bin folder: that'll depend on options your hosting package allows. Look at [Bottle](http://bottle.paws.de/) for a simple dispatcher which fits in a single Python module. You can deploy it using CGI,

```
import bottle
# Put your bottle code here, following the docs on the Bottle site
bottle.run(server=bottle.CGIServer)
```

**Further update:** Apart from the Bottle docs, I suggest you read the [Python docs about CGI](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi).

Comment: Worked great! Is there a way to get around the cgi-bin folder? Or perhaps use .htaccess to write it out of the url?

Comment: Last question, what is the simplest way to access get / post in Python, with this setup? Something akin to $_GET / $_POST in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Briefly you need modify your .htaccess file to allow Apache to interpret python file as cgi script, then write your python script with "#!/usr/bin/python" and don't forget to output http header (otherwise you will get a 500 internal error)

You can check [this post](http://redino.net/blog/2014/03/python-cgi-setup-hostgator-hosting/) to get the complete instruction

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Hostgator, but you want your web server to see your Python script as an executable CGI script.  That means making it executable and ensuring there's a #! in it and either putting it in `cgi-bin`, or setting your server to recognize `.py` as a CGI script file extension. [Here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/CgiScripts) is a simple example script and some context using the `cgi` module.